# modal bootstrap form edit in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am newbie in  CodeIgniter. I have a table where data is showing. In each row there is an edit button. When the edit button is clicked, a modal popup will pop up and then you are able to edit it. What my problem is, is that I don't know how to attach a link of my controller.

my view:

```html
<a href='<?php echo site_url();?>input_activity/edit/<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>' class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple" data-toggle="modal" >
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>
```

my controller:

```html
public function edit()
{
 $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
 $data=array(
 'content' =>'activity/v_updateactivity');
 $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
}
```

form edit:

```html
<!-- begin pop update activity -->
<div class="modal fade left" id=""> 
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
<div class="modal-content"> 
<div class="modal-header"> 
<h3 class="pull-left no-margin">Edit Activity</h3>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button> 
</div> 
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>input_activity/update"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="activity" class="col-sm-3 control-label">activity: </label> 
<div class="col-sm-9"> 
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="activity_name"  required><?php echo $detail[0]->name;?></textarea>
    
<button type="submit" class="btn green">
<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update</button>
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to provide id to the modal as same as link as below:

```html
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>">Edit</a>
```

For the first line of modal form::

```html
<div class="modal fade left" id="myModal<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>">
```

and then give form action as below:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller-name/function-name/<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>">
```

Comment: can you give me example controller

Comment: public function edit()
{
 $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
 $data=array(
 "activity_name" => $this->input->post('name_activity'), );                             
 $this->db->where('id',$id); $this->db->update('table_name',$data);  redirect();
}